# Elasticsearch regex to find phone number and email

Tags: regex, elasticsearch

I tried using a query to search for all those which are like phone numbers or/and email within elasticsearch.

Unfortunately, I can't find correct syntax for it.

```
{
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
      "biography": {
        "value": PHONE_NUMBER_REGEXP || EMAIL_REGEX # <-- problem is here
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Maybe somebody has a solution.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To express OR logic within regex, you need to use an *alternation*, which consists of two sub-patterns separated by a single `|`.  Consider:

```regex
^(?:\+65[0-9]{8}|\S+@gmail\.com)$
```

This would match any Singapore phone number starting with `+65` or any Gmail email address.

Following the comment by @Val below, the actual pattern you would use in ELK would not use `^` and `$` anchors:

```
{
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
      "biography": {
        "value": "\+65[0-9]{8}|\S+@gmail\.com"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: A quick side note that the `regexp` query in Elasticsearch doesn't accept `$` and `^` but the OR operator is ok: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/regexp-syntax.html#regexp-unsupported-operators